# Does camel allow to understand previous(source) pipileine in case of multiple from statements?

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

camel route:

```
 from("file://" + REST_FILES + "?idempotent=true")
     .from("file://" + FTP_FILES + "?idempotent=true")
     .process(new Processor() {
         @Override
         public void process(Exchange exchange) {
         }
```

Is it possible to understand inside `process` method - was exchange obtained from REST_FILES or from FTP_FILES ?

Comment: You cannot use multiple `from` in a route like this.

Comment: @pvpkiran Why, it works good

Answer (score 1):

I would think from a maintenance and test perspective it would be better to split this into three different routes.

Route 1 receives from the first file endpoint and sends it to new route that does the processing.

Route 2  receives from the first file endpoint and sends it to new route that does the processing.

Route 3 which is the new route does the actual processing.

You can then set an Exchange property from route 1 and 2 that identifies which route the message is coming from and then in route 3 make a decision on what to do based on that property.